# Multiple conditions evaluation order and priority in lua

Tags: lua

I need to evaluate a condition like:

```
condition1 and (condition2 or condition3)
```

where `condition2` and `condition3` should be evaluated only if `condition1` is true.
How do I write this in lua?

Is next code correct?

```
if condition1 and (condition2 or condition3) then
...
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Lua manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.4):

> Both `and` and `or` use short-cut evaluation; that is, the second operand is evaluated only if necessary.

So in the expression `condition1 and (condition2 or condition3)`, `condition2 or condition3` is only evaluated if `condition1` is true.

Note that this also means in the expression `condition2 or condition3`, `condition3` is only evaluated if `condition2` is false.